# Momentum transfer from gravitational wave

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

There has been some discussion here of the magnitude of the tidal distortion caused by a wave of the type reported on Feb. 11 2015, with the conclusion being that a tidal (distortion) effect perceptible on human scale only happens within a few 1000 km of the coalescing black holes. However, the discussion of the event includes the fact that $3M_{\odot}$  of energy were released in the form of gravitational waves. Given that these outgoing waves also carry momentum, what would be the effect on a test particle? Presumably a test mass would "feel" nothing - it would simply find its velocity changed by some $\Delta v$ relative to distant points after the passage of the wave. The question is, what is $\Delta v$ (as a function of $r$ and probably angle relative to the plane of the inspiral)?

Comment: The test masses "feel" strain in one direction and stress in another. It's the same as the spaghettification that happens as one gets close to a strongly gravitating body. You could easily observe this effect on e.g. the ISS, which makes it pretty boring, really.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I meant a _point_ test mass.

Comment: A point test mass doesn't feel anything due the equivalence principle. The LIGO detector is basically made to have an effective size of 1600km, that's barely large enough to detect these waves at this distance. If we were closer, a much smaller detector would do, of course. In the past people have built cryogenic detectors which were basically resonant aluminum cylinders on the 1m scale, but they are just not sensitive enough as far as I know.